Propane furnace blowing cold air on a 90 degree day with the thermostat turned off
We have an older Williamson propane furnace. It was installed 26 years ago.  Our thermostat is an older White-Rodgers model with just the peg on the side to slide up or down to set the temperature you want the house heated to.  In the warm months we slide the peg down to 50 degrees.  Yesterday was a 90 degree day. I got home from work and the furnace was blowing cold air.  I turned the furnace off for 30 seconds and back on and the blower immediately started blowing cold air again.  It runs for a minute or two then cuts off.  But then after another minute comes right back on blowing cold air.  I have just turned the furnace off and left it off.  Any ideas?

Assuming there is no air conditioning function, the only way I can see that you would get cold air would be a propane leak. In which case exit immediately and call the fire department...

by cold you mean ~room temp, not chilled air?
